# Jackson2 and Lombok @Builder

Tags: java, lombok

Given I have the POJO:

```
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;

@Data
@Builder
public class SomeResponse {
  private String author;
  private String authorTitle;
  private String teaser;
  private String text;
  private Long lastModified;
  private Long created;
  private Integer rating;

  private Optional<Markdown> markdown;
  private Optional<Integer> wordCount;
}
```

When I try to use the POJO in such normal Jackson construction:

```
restTemplate.getForObject(urlTemplate, SomeResponse.class,      
      productId.toString(), siteId.toString());
```

I get an exception, because there are private ctor in the `SomeResponse` class due to Lombok `@Builder` annotation.

How can I make it works without deleting Lombok `@Builder` annotation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also add `@AllArgsConstructor` and `@NoArgsConstructor`, possible with the right `access` values. See [the documentation](https://projectlombok.org/features/Constructor.html) for appropriate parameters.

Disclosure: I am a lombok developer.